# need to flatten list to use intersect in R

Tags: r, list, set-intersection

I have fullname data that I have used strsplit() to get each element of the name.

```
# Dataframe with a `names` column (complete names)
df <- data.frame(
    names =
          c("Adam, R, Goldberg, MALS, MBA", 
          "Adam, R, Goldberg, MEd", 
          "Adam, S, Metsch, MBA", 
          "Alan, Haas, MSW", 
          "Alexandra, Dumas, Rhodes, MA", 
          "Alexandra, Ruttenberg, PhD, MBA"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Add a column with the split names (it is actually a list)
df$splitnames <- strsplit(df$names, ', ')
```

I also have a list of degrees below

```
degrees<-c("EdS","DEd","MEd","JD","MS","MA","PhD","MSPH","MSW","MSSA","MBA",
           "MALS","Esq","MSEd","MFA","MPA","EdM","BSEd")
```

I would like to get the intersection for each name and respective degrees.

I'm not sure how to flatten the name list so I can compare the two vectors using intersect. When I tried `unlist(df$splitname,recursive=F)` it returned each element separately. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `lapply(df$splitname, intersection, degrees)`?

Comment: @agstudy, yes. untested (and thus typo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df$intersect <- lapply(X=df$splitname, FUN=intersect, y=degrees)
```

That will give you a list of the intersection of each element in `df$splitname` (*e.g.* `intersect(df$splitname[[1]], degrees)`). If you want it as a vector:

```
sapply(X=df$intersect, FUN=paste, collapse=', ')
```

I assume you need it as a vector, since possibly the complete names came from one (for instance, from a dataframe), but strsplit outputs a list.

Does that work? If not, please try to clarify your intention.

Good luck!

Comment: The `unlist(df$intersect)` would not have the suggested consequences, since each name can contain one or more degrees. I fixed it in the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking about it the wrong. The added hint about  making it a vector helps too.

Answer (score 0):

For continuity, you can use `unlist` :

```
hh <- unlist(df$splitname)
intersect(hh,degrees)
```

For example :

```
ll <- list(c("Adam" ,    "R"    ,    "Goldberg" ,"MALS"  , "MBA "),
           c("Adam" ,    "R"    ,    "Goldberg", "MEd" ))

 intersect(hh,degrees)
[1] "MEd"
```

or equivalent to :

```
hh[hh %in% degrees]
[1] "MEd"
```

To get differences you can use

```
setdiff(hh,degrees)
[1] "Adam"     "R"        "Goldberg" "MALS"     "MBA "
```

...

Comment: Since the problem appears to be determining the degree from each name, answers should be assigned to the same records (*i.e.* degrees associated with originating name), so unlist really is not an option because any name could have more than one degree (in fact, it happens in the example data).